# How do you validate a new user's account on PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I am using PHP for my project. How can I prompt a new user to enter their email address so I can send a verification link to their?

Comment: You, um... never mind. No code = too broad + unclear.

Comment: Here: http://daveismyname.com/login-and-registration-system-with-php-bp a whole package; have fun. *You're welcome* ;)

Comment: Why am I seeing this link in 2 random posts... :')

Comment: @DarkBee If you're referring to mine, it's one of the better amongst many. Seems like so many are using unsafe methods. May as well give 'em a better method, plus it's an "out of the box" solution ;)

Comment: Please do not vandalize your own posts - the internet is an archive and should be treated to such. If you want to remove the question you can delete your own question in the same area of links where "edit" exists.

Comment: @sjagr I can't delete it- I got this error message when I clicked delete- Sorry, this question has answers and cannot be deleted; flat it for moderator attention instead.

Comment: @sjagr- Any alternatives?

Comment: @NashTamu I have flagged it on your behalf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a simple form html like this :

form.html :

```
  <form action="submit.php" method="post">
      <input type="email" name='email'>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="send">
  </form>
```

submit.php :

```
   <?php

       if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST['email'] )){
          $email = $_POST['email'];
          // you've got the email so far , you can do what ever you want with it 
         // for example : you can send email or ...

         $to      = $email;
         $subject = 'the subject';
         $message = 'hello';
         $headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
             'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
             'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

         mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

       }else{

           echo "You can go fuzz yourself :D";
     }

    ?>
```

This is not safe and nor a powerful way of sending email , I just wanted to give you the hint , so be sure to check user inputs and so on ...

Comment: `if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST['email'])){...}` ;) Plus, [**filtering email**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) is a good thing.

Comment: I have +1 because it's a basic method that works. The OP has enough to go on from there and in comments also.